# Why is the alignment setting disabled on my Constant Power audio transition?

Tags: premiere

Can anyone tell me what would be causing me to not be able to set the Alignment property on a Constant Power audio transition?

I'm not sure what other information is relevant for this question as I am quite new to Adobe Premiere Pro CC.

[image]

I am using `Adobe Premiere Pro CC 7.2.2`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. For me, there was a very small gap between the 2 clips, which was not visible until I expanded the time sequence to a greater extent. Once I remove the gap between clips, alignment got enabled for me

Answer (score 0):

I think this is happening because you do not have enough material in one of your two clips to make a crossfade between your two clips.  Try overlapping the clips further, then applying a crossfade, and see if this fixes it, or make the duration of your crossfade shorter.